# Как из таблицы вытащить элемент по 2 параметрам и изменить laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Каким образом мне вытащить элемент из таблицы в БД по 2 параметрам и изменить например его текст. Вот ,что пробовал:

```
public function ajaxComments(Request $request)
{


    // записываем наёденную строку из БД в переменную
    $itComment = Comments::where(['userId':$request->userId,
                                  'companyId':$request->companyId,
                                 ])

    // проверяем, если данные в ней есть, то перезаписываем (вообще не уверен в коде ниже т.к не знаю как обновить данные в таблице)
    if ($itComment){
        $itComment= $request->name;
        $itComment= $request->INN;
        $itComment= $request->informC;
        $itComment= $request->nameDirec;
        $itComment= $request->addressC;
        $itComment= $request->phoneC;
        $itComment->save();
        return redirect(route('home'));
    }else{
        //если не нашли то создаём новый комментарий
        $comments = new Comments();
        $comments->idUser = $request->userId;
        $comments->idCompany = $request->companyId;
        $comments->comName = $request->name;
        $comments->comINN = $request->INN;
        $comments->comInform = $request->informC;
        $comments->comNameDirec = $request->nameDirec;
        $comments->comAddress = $request->addressC;
        $comments->comPhone = $request->phoneC;
        $comments->save();
        return redirect(route('home'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130962/discussion-on-question-by--------2-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все гораздо проще) Просто используй 2 раза where. Cмотри:

```
$itComment = Comments::where('userId', $request->userId)->where('companyId', $request->companyId)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ajaxComments(Request $request)
{
    $comment = Comment::where([
                                  'userId' => $request->userId,
                                  'companyId' => $request->companyId,
                                 ])->firstOrCreate();
    $comment= $request->name;
    $comment= $request->INN;
    $comment= $request->informC;
    $comment= $request->nameDirec;
    $comment= $request->addressC;
    $comment= $request->phoneC;
    $comment->save();
    return redirect(route('home'));
}
```

Отредактировал немного ваш код. Не забудьте $userId и $companyId добавить в массив $fillable